# iphone navigation controler and table view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

In my iphone app i have a button which changes the view (to another xib file).

How can i have this xib file to contain a navigation controller with a back button (which is at the top) and the bottom part a table view that has a scrollbar?

I assume that i have to use navigation controller, uiscrollview and uitableview but i am not sure how to combine these properly in the Interface Builder.

Can anyone help me out here?

EDIT: Thanks for your answers.
One annoying thing in XCode is that when you create a new xib file, you only get the empty version. However, if you create a new project for a specific purpose then you get a navigation, tab based or any other generated properly. Is there a better way to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

The one big mistake when i started to write to iphone was that i created NavContoller and Tab controller separately. always create just tab contoller and then configure  in this tab controller navigation controller.

there is tutorial video how to do this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

Answer (score 0):

For UINavigationController, when you click the button to change the view. you just use :
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController].

In the nib file, you add the navigationItem and then set the leftButton to the backButton. You can also drag the UITableViewController to the view.

Comment: yes, but when you have created a new xib file (which is of no certain type) what steps do you follow then to get the uinavcontroller and uitablecontroller working properly within interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create new "Navigation-based Application" and copy the code from there. Its a perfect example of what you are trying to do, but without the view switching (which you already seem to have done).

Br,
Paul Peelen

Comment: hi paul,
i edited my question. the only way to get these examples is by creating a new project and copying the code from there, right? how awful is that?

Comment: well, you don't have to copy the code if you don't want to. You can use the code as an example and create your own. But why re-inventing the wheel? Apple does have a very good example in that code which you can basically copy (and adapt to your preferences).

Comment: sure yes. my point was that i would expect when adding an xib file or a viewcontroller class to be able to select a template.

Comment: Ah, ok... sorry, missunderstood you. As far as I know... no template is available thru xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but from your question it seems as if you should go with a full navigation-based application. Start reading [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
It will make it all a lot easier, e.g. no need for dealing with back buttons by yourself.

(by the way: [TableViewS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) scroll on their own)

Comment: i am not sure that a full navigation-based app is what i need. parts of my app will need navigation. the issue mainly arises as to how i combine some different sets together.

cheers for the tableview tip